# Auto Create Dimensions in Android

Tags: java, android, xml

I am developing for android and I am using the Android Studio.I have many XML files and I never used the dimens.xml. Now I want to use it, but I don't want to go through the pains of creating a dimension for each view. I was wondering if there is a programming out there that can automatically do this, or if there is a function in Android Studio to create the dimension for every view that I have. Something simple, as in fewest clicks as possible. Otherwise, I might consider writing a script.

Comment: Only a human would know which numerical dimensions should map to the same named value. A script that just created a unique value in dimensions.xml for every dimension value would still leave things kind of a mess

Comment: I feel like it should be able to since all of my views have ids. It could also make arbitrary names according to the file name.

Comment: Thats kind of what I mean though. They are arbitrary names and not re-used at all like hand-created dimensions would be.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry I know it was too late for the answer...There is no auto create dimension.But there is already dimension are created by a person.

[Click this link to Download the dimension](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B5wPKdwkXs5YZWpha2pSSXZscTA?usp=sharing)

here you can see different types of dimension for different screen size...
you can download individually or all together. Download and paste it in the res folder.
**P.S:** Please copy the dimens.xml from vlaues(in the site) and paste in your project res > values...

Update:there is also another way. Paste this code in gradle and sync

> compile 'com.intuit.sdp:sdp-android:1.0.3

Hope It helps...